# Updating filter.xml of aem package using curl

Tags: curl, package, aem, cql

I want to create aem package using CURL. I am unable to add filters to the package.

I have tried the below commands where I am able to create and build a package using 1st and 3rd commands but unable to add filter uing 2nd command.

## create package

curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/my_packages/testpackage?cmd=create -d packageName=testpackage -d groupName=my_packages

## add filters

curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/update.jsp -F path=/etc/packages/my_packages/testpackage.zip -F packageName=testpackage -F groupName=my_packages -F {filter="[{\'root\' : \'/content/wucom/nam/ca/en/contactus-success\'}]"} -F '*charset*=UTF-8'

## build package

curl -u admin:admin -X POST http://localhost:4502/crx/packmgr/service/.json/etc/packages/my_packages/testpackage.zip?cmd=build

The built package does not have any filter.

Answer (score 2):

Since the /crx/packmgr/service.jsp doesn't support creation of filters, you could instead do the following:

1. Create a proper META-INF/vault/filter.xml file on the file system.
2. Download the package zip file:

   curl -u admin:admin http://localhost:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/testpackage.zip
3. Extract the filter.xml file from the zip using the jar command:

   jar -xvf testpackage.zip META-INF/vault/filter.xml
4. Edit the extracted META-INF/vault/filter.xml file.
5. Update the zip file with the new filter.xml using jar -uvf command:

   jar -uvf testpackage.zip META-INF/vault/filter.xml

See this article for some sample code on how to generate a package filter.xml using python code:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/How-to-build-a-package-from-an-XPath-query-without-installing-any-tools-to-the-AEM-instance-AEM.html

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the command that helps create filter and is working with AEM 6.4. Creating and building package are relatively simpler tasks and those have been skipped to keep the post succinct  -

```
    curl -X POST \  http://Host:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/content_backup2.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/ \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 8ae9290f-af72-44a4-808c-658a7130d5f1' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F _charset_=utf-8 \
  -F jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured \
  -F :nameHint=filter
```

This command will create a filter node beneath vlt:definition inside the package.

Then creating sub-filter nodes is simple as well. This will take content backup of the the complete content node tree. You can replace "*-F root=/content*" with your requirement-

```
curl -X POST \  http://host:4502/etc/packages/my_packages/content_backup2.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/ \
  -H 'Postman-Token: bc168785-94dd-4b99-a302-4b0a70b7225c' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F _charset_=utf-8 \
  -F jcr:primaryType=nt:unstructured \
  -F mode=replace \
  -F root=/content \
  -F :nameHint=f0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="damFilterForm" method="POST" action="/etc/packages/local_packages/packageWithFiltersYo.zip/jcr:content/vlt:definition/filter/f0" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="damPath" type="hidden" name="root" value="/"/>
        <input id="damPath" type="hidden" name="jcr:primaryType" value="nt:unstructured"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="replace"/>
        <input id="helperDamSubmit" type="Submit" value="Submit DAM" style="display:none" />
    </form>
```

$("#damFilterForm").submit();

**Please note: The filter can be added like this, just that this gives a renderer that isn't user friendly and there seems now way to get it back to the main referrer JSP. i.e. the redirect URL is the filter node itself. And to get it back to the form is quite a task.**